# Sublime Text snippet priority

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I made my own snippet with a Tab trigger that inserts a big comment block into a CSS file when triggered with the keyword `comment`. After using it for a while and it working fine, I've installed the Emmet plugin, which inserts some of its own code when triggered by Tab on any arbitrary word or character combination.

So what happens now is that the Emmet plugin is overriding my snippet, and instead of getting my big comment block when typing "comment" and pressing Tab, I get `comment: ;` because Emmet is assuming that I want to write a CSS property named `comment`.

(which doesn't even make sense because I'm not in a `{}` block, but that's not the point)

My question is, how can I get my own snippet to execute with a "higher priority", so that if there is a snippet with the current Tab trigger, the Emmet plugin will be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing away from tab completion:
https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/9

The simple workaround is to change the trigger for your snippet to `mycomment` or `commment` or some other memorable but unique trigger to remove the whole issue of conflicts.